# Passing env variables to a ssh connection

Tags: bash, ssh, zsh, environment-variables

I want to pass enviromental variables to a ssh connection. They should be passed dynamically, therefore hard-coding them into the config file of ssh
won't work for me.

I've tried this:

```
   AAA="tatata" ssh my_user@my_server.com
   echo $AAA
   ====> (empty)
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 7):

Ssh only passes only the `TERM` environment variable through (+ `LANG` and `LC_*` in many default configs **^1**). Changing the server's configuration to accept any environment variables can have serious consequences (allowing a user to bypass their login shell and any `ForceCommand`), and **you should not do it**.

Instead of trying to pass them through ssh, you could set them on the right side, as part of the "remote command" argument(s), and start an interactive login shell explicitly:

```
ssh -t user@host AAA=tatata bash -l
```

The `-t` option is to let `ssh` allocate a pseudo-terminal, something it won't do by default when a remote command is specified. The `-l` option of bash is to let it run a login shell, i.e. to let it source `~/.bash_login`, and simulate as closely as possible the way it's run when no remote command arguments are specified to ssh.

Since the values of the environment variables will be expanded twice, both on the local and on the remote side, you should **double quote** them, which may turn nasty fast:

```
ssh -t user@host PRICE=\\\$19 bash -l
```

---

But if your configuration allows the `LC_*` envvars through, you could just name your variables that way ;-)

```
LC_AAA=tatata ssh user@host
```

or, if your ssh *client* config does not include `LC_*` in `SendEnv`:

```
LC_AAA=tatata ssh -o SendEnv=LC_AAA user@host
```

**^1** In order to be able to pass extra envvars through ssh, both `AcceptEnv` on the server and `SendEnv` on the client are needed. Look for those directives in `ssh*_config` to see what their defaults are on your system(s).

Comment: Then I'll change the configuration of a server to accept any environment variables

Comment: Note that `${var@Q}` is only "safe" to use if the login shell of user@host is bash, of the same version as on the local host and the OS and locale are the same on the two hosts. I'd avoid using any quoting operators that doesn't  use only single quotes (use zsh's `${(qq)VAR}` for instance). See [Escape a variable for use as content of another script](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/600214) for details.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks, I've got rid of that, instead of trying to explain that the remote shell should support `$'...'`, etc.

Comment: (just to clarify my previous comment, using zsh's `${(qq)VAR}` should be safe but only if the login shell of user@host is Bourne-like. More on that at [How to execute an arbitrary simple command over ssh without knowing the login shell of the remote user?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/205567)