# Variable username in SSH config

Tags: ssh, variable

I am looking for a way to parse a variable to the SSH config file.
Currently I have a script that replaces the values before distribution. I'd rather eliminate this step.
I've been over the manual several times aswel as the release notes but without succes, currently not sure if this is even possible.

Preferably I'd do something like this:

```
variable_user = boxuser

Host thisbox
         Hostname thisbox
         User $variable_user
```

Ideally I'd want to include the config with the user variable so that everything else can remain standardised.

Am I asking too much?

**Edit:**

Passing $USER is not interpreted by the config

```
Host thisbox    
   Hostname thisbox 
   User $USER
```

Result:

```
$ ssh thisbox 
$USER@thisbox's password:
```

The same goes for %u

Answer (score 3):

Use the `$USER` environment to set a user

```
Host MYHOST
    Hostname MYHOST
    User $USER
```

Check this for more `SSH Environment Variables`

[SSH Environment Variables](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/ssh-the-secure/0596008953/apes12.html)

[Passing env variables to a ssh connection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612493/passing-env-variables-to-a-ssh-connection)

[SSH - set env vairables by every connection](https://serverfault.com/questions/388826/ssh-set-env-vairables-by-every-connection-godaddy-shared-host)

[When ssh'ing, how can I set an environment variable on the server that changes from session to session?](https://superuser.com/questions/163167/when-sshing-how-can-i-set-an-environment-variable-on-the-server-that-changes-f)

Other reasons environment variables are not being interpreted on the client side:

1. is the environment variable `set correctly`
2. is the environment variable `exported`
3. Check the `ssh_config` for `SendEnv`, is your environment variable listed
   `SendEnv ENV_VARIABLE`
4. Try using the -t option `ssh -t ...`
5. Create a `~/.ssh/environment` file on the client
   `ENV_VARIABLE=VALUE`
   Set `PermitUserEnvironment` to yes on the server in `sshd_config` file

> If you are trying to use user environment variables in an SSH session and they are not being interpreted,maybe that your ssh client is not configured to pass your environment variables.
> To pass environment variables, you can use the -t option when you connect to the host. This option tells SSH to allocate a pseudo-tty on the remote host, which allows environment variables to be passed
>
> You may need to check your SSH client configuration or the documentation of your client

or

Use the `SendEnv` and `AcceptEnv` directives

Add this to you `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

`AcceptEnv SSH_USER`

[sshd_config(5) — Linux manual page | AcceptEnv](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html)

or

Use the `$SSH_USER` environment to set a use, maybe this will not work on all systems

```
Host MYHOST
    Hostname MYHOST
    User $SSH_USER
```

When you run the ssh command, it will read the value of the SSH_USER environment variable to replace the $SSH_USER

You will need to set the SSH_USER environment variable every time you open a new terminal session or add it to your `~/.bashrc` to make it persist.

`Search in the Bash CookBook for $SSH_USER`, there are a view chapters, I only mentioned one:

Check this chapters:

**10.3 Using Configuration Files in a Script**

**15.11 Getting Input from Another Machine**

[Bash CookBook](https://terrorgum.com/tfox/books/bashcookbook.pdf)

> 10.3 Using Configuration Files in a Script
> Problem
> You want to use one or more external configuration files for one or more scripts.
> Solution
> You could write a lot of code to parse some special configuration file format. Do
> yourself a favor and don’t do that. Just make the config file a shell script and use the
> solution in Recipe 10.2.
> Discussion
> This is just a specific application of sourcing a file. However, it’s worth noting that
> you may need to give a little thought to how you can reduce all of your configuration
> needs to bash-legal syntax. In particular, you can make use of Boolean flags and
> optional variables (see Chapter 5 and Recipe 15.11):

```
# In config file
VERBOSE=0 # 0 or '' for off, 1 for on
SSH_USER='jbagadonutz@' # Note trailing @, set to '' to use the current user
# In script
[ "$VERBOSE" ] || echo "Verbose msg from $0 goes to STDERR" >&2
[...]
ssh $SSH_USER$REMOTE_HOST [...]
```

> Of course, depending on the user to get the configuration file correct can be chancy,
> so instead of requiring the user to read the comment and add the trailing @, we could
> do it in the script:

```
# If $SSH_USER is set and doesn't have a trailing @ add it:
[ -n "$SSH_USER" -a "$SSH_USER" = "${SSH_USER%@}" ] && SSH_USER="$SSH_USER@"
```

> or just use:

```
ssh ${SSH_USER:+${SSH_USER}@}${REMOTE_HOST} [...]
```

> to make that same substitution right in place. The bash variable operator :+ will do
> the following: if $SSH_USER has a value, it will return the value to the right of the :+
> (in this case we specified the variable itself along with an extra @); otherwise, if unset
> or empty, it will return nothing.
> See Also
> • Chapter 5
> • Recipe 10.2, “Reusing Code with Includes and Sourcing”
> • Recipe 15.11, “Getting Input from Another Machine”
>
> Discussion
> We do a few interesting things here. First, notice how both $SSH_USER and $SSH_ID
> work. They have an effect when they have a value, but when they are empty they
> interpolate to the empty set and are ignored. This allows us to abstract the values in
> the code, which lends itself to putting those values in a configuration file, putting the
> code into a function, or both.

Comment: @Peregrino69 it was a custom environment variable sry, wrong system i forgot that we adjusted a lot in our ssh environment we also use variable usernames in the scripts

Comment: Upvoted. Too bad can't do it twice :-)

Comment: Passing $USER is not interpreted by the config: ssh thisbox gives:
$USER@localhost's password:

Answer (score 1):

The $USER doesn't work on all systems or version if you don't have a customized bash/ssh environment, because bash does not interpret your ssh config file

You can fix this with
your .bashrc file or create a custom_ssh file, source it over .bashrc file
and create alias or variable

~/.bashrc

```
# add to the end of file
source custom_ssh_config
```

custom_ssh_config file use alias

```
#!/bin/bash

# USE ALIAS
alias ssh_user_1="ssh ${USER}@HOSTNAME"

user2="myuser2"
alias ssh_user_2="ssh -l ${user2} thisbox"
```

Run:
`ssh_user_1` or `ssh_user_2`

custom_ssh_config file use variable

```
#!/bin/bash

# USE VARIABLE
ssh_user_1="${USER}"

user2="myuser2"
ssh_user_2="${user2}"
```

Run:

`ssh -l $ssh_user_1 thisbox` or `ssh -l $ssh_user_2 thisbox`

For $USER:
`ssh -l $USER thisbox`

you don't need User $USER in your ssh config file

Comment: But that would defeat the use of the SSH config file, it's way too complex and long to be rewritten in aliases. Thanks for the suggestion but it's not a solution :)